# shared Preferences doesn't work on some keys

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

In my application I'm using Shared Preferences to save my app settings.

here is the way I define a Shared Prefrences:

```
sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.last_update_key),MODE_PRIVATE);
String shared = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.last_update_key),"0");
```

and my ASyncTask onPostExecute block that uses passed Shared Preferences:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(result == "true"){

        textView.setText(R.string.updated_message);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(context.getString(R.string.last_update_key),getCurrentTimeStamp());
        try {
            editor.putString("s_app_name",json3.getJSONObject(0).getString("value"));
            editor.putString("s_township_name",json3.getJSONObject(1).getString("value"));
            editor.putString("s_welcome_message",json3.getJSONObject(2).getString("value"));

        }catch (JSONException e){
        }
        editor.commit();

    }
```

but the strings that I put them in try block will not display in my activity and I do not get any error in catch.
here is how I get my saved value :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            getString(R.string.last_update_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String welcome_message = sharedPref.getString("s_welcome_message","");
```

the problem is that I can get the value of `R.string.last_update_key` but not the others.

Comment: can log add log inside the catch to display the exception error?

Comment: There is no exception error!

Comment: The code looks ok. Seems the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: are you sure that the JSON has values ?

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad. I have to place my code outside of "if" block

Comment: the problem that you should not use == in strings, because it always false, instead, you should use the method .equals() 
the strings in java is object and == matching the references not the value

Comment: @AmjadOmari you're not quite right. comparing string with == is true if the string is the same. E.g: `String a = "test"; String b = "test"; if (a == b) // this is will return true`. More at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java